# Angular Multiple directive asking for transclution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having the following error and it is driving me mad because it happens in a random way :

Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [dsRegion, dsRegion] asking for transclusion on: 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$compile/multidir?p0=dsRegion&p1=&p2=dsRe…n-change%3D%22componentSelected%22%20ds-region-get-data%3D%22getData%22%3E

What I am trying to is to add 'dsRegion', directive in a sort of template rendered in the backen. I am including the template using and ng-include directive. The template can contain several regions in which I use the 'dsRegion' directive in order to add a sort of toolbar.

```
angular 1.6.2
```

My inclusion div

```
<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()" class="template"></div>
```

dsRegion directive

```
app.register.directive('dsRegion', [function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope :{
        dsRegion : '=',
        dsRegionChange : '&',
        dsRegionGetData: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: '../views/utils/template/template-region.html',
    transclude: true,
    link : function (scope, attr) {
        scope.mainAttr = attr;
        scope.regionId = scope.dsRegion;
        (function () {
            scope.handleRegionInformation(scope.dsRegionChange()(scope.regionId, null, true));
        })();

    },
    controller : function ($scope, $mdDialog, localStorageFactory) {
        $scope.componentNameMapper = {
            0 : {
                name : DSComponent.name,
                controller: DSComponentEditorController,
                view: '../views/utils/template/components/DSComponent.template.html',
                lsKey: localStorageFactory.lsKeys.componentDSKey,
                restoreTemplate: true,
                restoreTemplateFunction : 'assignAllDataDSComponent'
            },
            1 : {
                name : URLComponent.name,
                controller: URLComponentEditorController,
                view : '../views/utils/template/components/URLComponent.template.html',
                lsKey: localStorageFactory.lsKeys.componentURLKey,
                restoreTemplate: false
            }
        };

        $scope.openMenu = function($mdMenu, $event) {
            $mdMenu.open($event);
        };

        $scope.title = 'Editor de contenido';
        $scope.componentName = null;
        $scope.regionTitle = 'REGI\u00D3N NO ASIGNADA';
        $scope.component = false;
        $scope.currentComponent = {};

        $scope.deleteItem = function ($mdMenu) {
            $mdMenu.close();
            $scope.title = 'Editor de contenido';
            $scope.componentName = null;
            $scope.regionTitle = 'REGI\u00D3N NO ASIGNADA';
            $scope.component = false;
            $scope.currentComponent = {};
            $scope.dsRegionChange()($scope.regionId);
        };

        var setComponentEditionInfo = function (comp) {
            Object.keys($scope.componentNameMapper).forEach(function (key) {
                if($scope.componentNameMapper[key].name === comp.name) {
                    $scope.currentComponent.meta = $scope.componentNameMapper[key];
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.handleRegionInformation = function (result) {
            if(result) {
                $scope.currentComponent.info = result;
                setComponentEditionInfo(result);
                $scope.component = true;
                $scope.componentName = 'para ' + result.displayName;
                $scope.regionTitle = 'REGI\u00D3N : ' + result.displayName.toUpperCase();
            }
        };

        $scope.item = function (item) {
            $scope.handleRegionInformation($scope.dsRegionChange()($scope.regionId, item));
        };

        $scope.getData = function () {
            return $scope.dsRegionGetData()();
        };
        $scope.setCurrentComponent = function (current) {
            Object.keys($scope.currentComponent.info).forEach(function(keys) {
                $scope.currentComponent.info[keys] = current.info[keys];
            });
            if(current.meta.restoreTemplate) {
                $scope.getData()[current.meta.restoreTemplateFunction]
                ($scope.currentComponent.info);
            }
        };

        $scope.showComponentEditor = function (event) {
            localStorageFactory.removeDataFromLocalStorage($scope.currentComponent.meta.lsKey);
            localStorageFactory.setDataToLocalStorage($scope.currentComponent.meta.lsKey,
                $scope.currentComponent);
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: $scope.currentComponent.meta.controller,
                templateUrl: $scope.currentComponent.meta.view,
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: event,
                clickOutsideToClose: false,
                escapeToClose: false,
                resolve: {
                    component : function () {
                        return {
                            currentComponent: $scope.currentComponent.info,
                            getData: $scope.getData
                        };
                    }
                }
            }).then(function() {
            }, function() {
                var lsData = localStorageFactory.getDataFromLocalStorage($scope.currentComponent.meta.lsKey).data;
                lsData.info.assignationDate = new Date(lsData.info.assignationDate);
                $scope.setCurrentComponent(lsData);
            });
        };
    }
};}]);
```

templateUrl page

```
<md-toolbar class="md-hue-2 _md _md-toolbar-transitions ">
<div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <span flex="" md-truncate="" class="flex">{{title}} {{componentName}}</span>
    <div ng-show="component">
        <div>
            <md-button aria-label="Open" class="md-icon-button edit-component" ng-click="showComponentEditor($event, regionId)">
                <md-icon md-menu-origin>create</md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <md-menu md-position-mode="target-right target" md-offset="8 42">
        <md-button aria-label="Open phone interactions menu" class="md-icon-button"
                   ng-click="openMenu($mdMenu, $event)">
            <md-icon md-menu-origin>settings</md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-menu-content width="2">
            <div>
                <md-menu-item>
                    <md-button ng-click="item(componentNameMapper[1])" ng-disabled="currentComponent.info">
                        <md-icon>http</md-icon>
                        P&aacute;gina WEB
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
                <md-menu-item>
                    <md-button ng-click="item(componentNameMapper[0])" ng-disabled="currentComponent.info">
                        <md-icon>local_movies</md-icon>
                        Lista de Reproducci&oacute;n
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
            </div>
            <md-menu-item >
                <md-button ng-click="deleteItem($mdMenu)" ng-disabled="!currentComponent.info">
                    <md-icon>clear</md-icon>
                    Eliminar
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
</div>
</md-toolbar>
<div class="blank">
<div>
    <span>{{regionTitle}}</span>
</div>
```

Sample template served from Backend

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/templates/hcc-template/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/templates/hccf-template/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="box">

     <div class="header" >

     <div class="region-container" ds-region="123" ds-region-    change='componentSelected' ds-region-get-data='getData'>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="container content">
    <div class="flex-div">

        <div class="region-container" ds-region="333" ds-region-change='componentSelected' ds-region-get-data='getData'>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="flex-div">

        <div class="region-container" ds-region="444" ds-region-change='componentSelected' ds-region-get-data='getData'>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

    <div class="region-container" ds-region="23423" ds-region-change='componentSelected' ds-region-get-data='getData'>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See if this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456294/angular-directive-asking-for-transclusion .  I wonder if <div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()" class="template"></div> is your problem.  Maybe test it with the file content instead of the ng-include to see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the ng-include I got the url of the template, which can be changed, so I am a bit stuck on that. I will try to add a plunker